# Systemd starts unknown openvpn instances - how could I disable this?

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, systemd, tail

this is my output by `tail -f /var/log/syslog/`.

```
May 26 08:02:29 ovpn-server systemd[1]: openvpn-server@ovpn-42.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 26 08:02:29 ovpn-server systemd[1]: openvpn-server@ovpn-42.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 26 08:02:29 ovpn-server systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN service for ovpn/42.
```

But there are not a config file like `ovpn-42.conf` at `/etc/openvpn/server/`. How could I debug this or better disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy and paste the unit name right out of the log entry, and then disable it.

```
systemctl disable openvpn-server@ovpn-42.service
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and for the love of god could not find the location of the invocation argument list.
However, I ran into:
https://lxadm.com/Enabling_OpenVPN_with_systemctl
and when I correctly enabled the services using:

```
systemctl enable openvpn@client.conf
```

the system seemed to reset itself and remove the non-existing targets.